# I can't see anonymous access menu in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, anonymous-access

I'm so confused because after **enabling anonymous access** in central administration panel on SharePoint 2010, I can't see the **Anonymous access** in the **Site Setting** -> **Site Permissions**

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you have a  tick on `Enable to anonymous access` from Central Administration of your web application.

than easy to find `Anonymous Access` Tab in Ribbon.

you should go into your Web application than click on  site action(Ribbon) -> site permissions ->  (Click on Edit tab of Ribbon) you may find out `Anonymous Access` Tab

[image]

Hops its helps!!

Comment: I know that, but in Site Permissions I can't see the Anonymous Access tab! It seems something disable or hide it.

Comment: Do you have a full access control of your web application?see this : http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Yes. I have an administrator account and Really I do all steps but after that, I can't see the Anonymous Access tab in Site Permissions...

Comment: try this might be helpful to u : In `Central Administration ->   select your web application -> than in Ribbon tab` you can see `User Policy` tab click on it and add your site administrator with full control. than check its

Answer (score 1):

GO to **CENTRAL ADMIN** --> Select your web application -->Click on **Authentication Providers**-- Click on **Default** and then select the checkbox  **Enable anonymous access** Click SAVE.. After this Restart your site, with this you should be able to See "Anonymous access"